# JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"#define RSAPrivateKey_dup GRPC_SHADOW_'

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

Steps I followed to add firestore to ios part of flutter

1. Create a new flutter app.
2. Ensure flutter run launches in ios simulator. It works fine.
3. Add cloud_firestore: 0.9.7 to the pubspec.yaml
4. then run the app,which leads to te error.

The Pod.lock file is not getting created

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
    name: dili_platform
description: A new Flutter application.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 0.9.7

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I am using Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52)

Comment: can you try`cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2` also tell result of `sudo gem which cocoapods`

Comment: the result of **sudo gem which cocoapods** is `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb`

Comment: I have tried `cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2 ` and I still get the same results

Answer (score 10):

Run these two commands:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/Spec_Lock
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/
```

then `pod install`.

[Source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9578#issuecomment-631070152)

Comment: WOW.... You just saved the day. Saving this somewhere for later.

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded  cocoapods following the instructions listed here [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41253#issuecomment-536039050], and then used the following firebase package :

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0
firebase_analytics: ^3.0.0
firebase_auth: ^0.11.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+1
cloud_functions: ^0.3.0
```

Looks its some compatibility issued with cocoapods v1.9.0